# sizeof mmap in c, how can we know how many memory do i alloc

Tags: c, sizeof, mmap

I am trying using mmap() in c to map the memory. After running the following code, it print 1, because of the sizeof(void*) is 1, so how can we know we did get 1234 bytes memory

```
void *heap_region = NULL;

heap_region = mmap(NULL, 1234, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
printf("%lx",sizeof(*heap_region));
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Let's start with that.

Comment: Does that really even compile?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `sizeof` for that purpose? Just because it has "size" and "of" in it? And no, `sizeof(void *)` is typically not 1. And your code does not even attempt to evaluate `sizeof(void *)`. It attempts to evaluate `sizeof(void)`, which is illegal in C.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: FWIW, I tried compiling it on my system, and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the call succeeded, this means you got (at least) the 1234 bytes you asked for.
You know the call succeeded if the returned pointer is not `MAP_FAILED`.
So you could say

```
if(heap_region == MAP_FAILED) {
    fprintf(stderr, "mmap failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
} else {
    printf("mmap succeeded: %p\n", heap_region)
    ...
}
```

Comment: The value returned by `mmap` for failure is `MAP_FAILED`, not `0`.

Comment: In fact, `0` can be a *successful* return value for `mmap()`. (Not often, but under the right circumstances.) I've edited the post to use the correct error value.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I appreciate it.  (Learned something!)